# BASH_REMATCH shows empty string after regex match

Tags: regex, bash, ubuntu-server

Just want to learn the BASH_REMATCH.

On ubuntu 16.10, I wrote a small script for BASH_REMATCH:

```
#!/bin/bash
x='sadas123fnrejkwhfklde'
if [[ $x =~ ([0-9]*) ]] 
then
  echo "match"
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo "not match"
fi
```

However, when /i ran this script, only the "match" shows up, not the captured match!

The bash version is:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`([0-9])*` matches zero or more occurrences of digits anywhere in the string.  So, it is yielding a null string, which is a valid match.

Change the expression to `([0-9]+)` so that it matches one or more digits.

```
#!/bin/bash
x='sadas123fnrejkwhfklde'
if [[ $x =~ ([0-9]+) ]]
then
  echo "match"
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
  echo "not match"
fi
```

yields

```
match
123
```

Comment: But is it the regular expression greedy? so even I used the * it should match the whole three digit numbers. Am I right?

Comment: yes it is greedy. the pattern `[0-9]*` matches the beginning of the string which does not start with a digit so even the greedy match is still empty.

Comment: for me it print "match" but NOT the numbers